# web pages stop rendering after iFrame loads

Tags: iframe

We have a web page in our solution that uses an iFrame to display a vendor's web page.  Usually when a user navigates away from this page that hosts the iFrame, all the other pages render just fine.  The vendor just redesigned the content of their page, however, and while their new page looks fine in the iFrame and that hosting page works fine too, any time a user navigates away from the hosting page, the page being redirected ~to~ does not render properly.  It's just completely blank.  An f5 will get it back, but I'm wondering what I can do to fix this.  The vendor says it's not their problem, but that's the only thing that changed.  I've tried both redirecting the iFrame to blank and removing it outright via javascript (see below), and while I can see the iFrame disappear just before the redirect, the redirected to page still will not render without hitting f5.

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function ()
    {
        document.getElementById('<%= ifr.ClientID %>').src = "about:blank"
        $("#<%= ifr.ClientID %>").remove();
    }
```

Can anyone give a suggestion of why this is happening and how to prevent it?
TIA
-VG

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem when using an iFrame containing a page from our payment card processor embedded in our eCommerce pages.  I couldn't see anything in the source of the iFrame that might be causing the problem, so I opened up space for the iFrame, contained it in a div (my last element on the page) and used position to render the iFrame in the position I wanted it.  Hardly responsive design, but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this from the first Google result, this can be caused by your iframe being self-closed (ending with `/>`). To fix it you just need to close the iframe with `</iframe>` instead. This may not be the original problem but it worked for me.